# PHP session regenerate id and unset old

Tags: php, session

Is there some correct way to regenerate session ID and unset old session?  I DONT WANT delete it, but only unset.
i have this function

```
function sessionRegenerateID(){

    session_start();
    $ses = $_SESSION;
    session_unset();
    session_write_close();

    session_start();
    session_regenerate_id();
    $_SESSION = $ses;

}
```

Comment: Just use `session_regenerate_id(true);`, nothing else.

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to delete the old session?

Comment: What do you mean by "unset old session"?